# How to stop Anchor tag from snaping page downward

Tags: html, css, url, redirect, scrollbar

I was wondering about a custom slider and its anchor tag which changes images when selected, specifically I want it to not say "index.html#slide-1" for when it is clicked on any, and in this example slide 1. It also snaps the page downward to be inline with the image, which I do not want.

This is what it looks like: [A picture of create mod website not working for display of custom slider.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lTttE.jpg)

The slider code is:

```html
        <section class="gallery">
    <h2>A short Image Gallery of Create</h2>
    <p>These images are some left over screenshots I had from the create mod trailer world. The link to the create
        mod trailer world download can be found here.</p>
    <div class="slider-wrapper">
        <div class="slider">
            <img id="slide-1" src="images/gallery-1.png" alt="An industrial Level Oven running off steam engines">
            <img id="slide-2" src="images/gallery-2.png" alt="An automatic milk farm">
            <img id="slide-3" src="images/gallery-3.png" alt="A movable roof coming down onto waterworks">
            <img id="slide-4" src="images/gallery-4.png"
                alt="A wheat conveyor belt, transferring and moving wheat from one place to another">
            <img id="slide-5" src="images/gallery-5.png"
                alt="A celebration of the cake being automated in the Trailer World">
        </div>
        <div class="slider-nav">
            <a href="#slide-1"></a>
            <a href="#slide-2"></a>
            <a href="#slide-3"></a>
            <a href="#slide-4"></a>
            <a href="#slide-5"></a>
        </div>
    </div>
        </section>
```

The CSS is this:

```css
.gallery {
  padding: 2rem;
}
.gallery h2 {
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: xx-large;
}
.gallery p {
  text-align: center;
  max-width: 700px;
  margin: 10px auto 20px;
  line-height: 1.4;
}
.slider-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  max-width: 48rem;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.slider {
  display: flex;
  aspect-ratio: 16/9;
  overflow-x: auto;
  scrollbar-width: none;
  position: relative;
  scroll-snap-type: x mandatory;
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
  box-shadow: 0 1.5rem 3rem -0.75rem hsla(0, 0%, 0%, 0.25);
  border-radius: 1.75rem;
}
.slider img {
  flex: 1 0 100%;
  scroll-snap-align: start;
  object-fit: cover;
  overflow-x: scroll;
}
.slider-nav {
  display: flex;
  column-gap: 1rem;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 1.25rem;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  z-index: 1;
}
.slider-nav a {
  width: 0.5rem;
  height: 0.5rem;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #fff;
  opacity: 75%;
  transition: opacity ease 250ms;
}
```

In summary I would like the URL to not redirect, and the page to not snap down when the slider is clicked on.

Comment: Just to make sure I understand fully. When the user clicks one of the dots, you want the related image to be shown but you don’t want screen contents to move. Is that correct?

Comment: Yep! And also stop the webpage from changing the url to say index.html#slide-3 if I were to click on slide 3.